# Python Text Menu Infinite Loop

Tags: python

I am making a simple text menu in Python and every time it gets to the while loop for the menu it just turns infinite.. I am not sure what's going on, I feel as if this should work correctly.

```
 # Menu system!
def menu():
        print "blahblah options"

loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        add(input("Add this: "),input("to this: "))
    elif choice == 2:
        sub(input("Subtract this: "),input("from this: "))
    elif choice == 3:
        mul(input("Multiply this: "),input("by this: "))
    elif choice == 4:
        div(input("Divide this: "),input("by this: "))
    elif choice == 5:
        loop = 0
```

What is happening here that is causing it to loop through the print statement at the top endlessly?

Comment: is `choice` ever set to 1 ? how is `menu()` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a line in `menu`, or else missing an `input` elsewhere. You're not actually accepting a choice from your user yet. If you want to keep your current structure, `menu` should look like:

```
def menu():
    print 'options...'
    return int(raw_input())
```

Or, a little cleaner (same effect):

```
def menu():
    return int(raw_input('options...'))
```

Otherwise, you can just call `menu()` and then separately accept the user's selection:

```
while loop == 1:
    menu()
    choice = int(raw_input())
```

**Note** that I've changed your `input()` calls to `int(raw_input())`. This is a *much* safer way of accepting input from your user, since it prevents them from embedding arbitrary Python code in their input!

---

**Not-quite-on-topic:**

Now, just because I happened to notice it, I'm also going to mention that `loop` is a potentially-misleading variable name. Since you're just using it as a boolean, you could rewrite the while loop like this:

```
loop = 1
while loop: # !
    #do stuff
```

This is kind of funny, but not very intuitive to read. It's usually better to simply loop indefinitely, and use `break` when your end condition is met:

```
while True:
    # Do stuff
    if choice == 5: #Or whatever end condition
        break
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I guess that would be important for them to make a selection, d'oh!

Answer (score 1):

`menu` is a function that prints something and returns `None`. When you do `choice=menu()`, choice is set to `None`. None of your `if` match and the loop repeats endlessly.

A better option would be to prompt user for input in `menu()` and return the user input. Remember to convert user input to `int` first (because you compare choice to an integer)

```
choice = int(raw_input("Enter your choice:"))
return choice
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing  options inside `menu` you should return them, because choice expects a return value from `menu()`, and as  `menu`  is not returning anything so the default return value None gets assigned to `choice` each time.

```
def menu():
        return "blahblah options"

loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:     #this is always None
        add(input("Add this: "),input("to this: "))
    elif choice == 2:
        sub(input("Subtract this: "),input("from this: "))
    elif choice == 3:
        mul(input("Multiply this: "),input("by this: "))
    elif choice == 4:
        div(input("Divide this: "),input("by this: "))
    elif choice == 5:
        loop = 0
```

Instead of returning  fixed values from menu you should take input from user:

```
def menu():
        strs = ('Enter 1 for addition\n'
                'Enter 2 for subtaction\n'
                'Enter 3 for multiplication\n'
                'Enter 4 for division\n'
                'Enter 5 to exit : ')
        choice = raw_input(strs)
        return int(choice) 

while True:          #use while True
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        add(input("Add this: "),input("to this: "))
    elif choice == 2:
        sub(input("Subtract this: "),input("from this: "))
    elif choice == 3:
        mul(input("Multiply this: "),input("by this: "))
    elif choice == 4:
        div(input("Divide this: "),input("by this: "))
    elif choice == 5:
        break
```

Comment: @Schorsch I think OP has not posted the original `menu`, I suppose he was using print 1, print 2 inside the menu definition.

Comment: That is the case, and when writing the original menu I forgot to add the input return :(

Comment: I love that it takes the input from the user, thank you. I wish I could select both as an answer!